# Excel VBA Sorting sheet when workbook is hidden

Tags: vba, excel

Hi guys I'm using a sorting code it was working fine until it didn't after a while of reading though the code and testing I found that the reason for the error was because of the select which as far as I know only work when you can select the sheet first with a visible worksheet and here comes my problem I need the code to work with a hidden workbook anybody that can help with getting the code to work with hidden workbook because I only know this code. Thanks!

what the code here does is sorting after B column but it have the row 1 as header

```
Set tsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Courses_tee")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Courses_tee").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: Ever heard of punctuation?

Comment: Well I'm very sorry Aganju that I'm not English and don't have any clue where to put them. it must have been so hard for you to read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Courses_tee").Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

To this:

```
Set tsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Courses_tee")
tSheet.Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

You don't need to, and you *shouldn't* `Select` or `Activate` things when you can operate directly on the objects instead. `Select` and `Activate` essentially mimic keystrokes/mouse-clicks/user actions -- you don't need to `Select` a range in your code if you know what that range *is*, i.e.:

```
Range("A1:A100").Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Range("B1")
```

Can become simply:

```
Range("A1:A100").Copy Destination:=Range("B1")
```

Etc.

More info:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Hi David thank you for your code and explaining. it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select

```
tSheet.Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=tSheet.Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```